# how to change xml tag to pascal case in php

Tags: php, xml

```
<?php
function array_to_xml(array $arr, SimpleXMLElement $xml)
{
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        is_array($v)
            ? ucwords(array_to_xml($v, $xml->addChild($k)))
            : ucwords($xml->addChild($k, $v));
    }
    return $xml;
}

$test_array = array (
  'blaPo' => '1',
  'Items' => '1',
    'another_array' => array (
        'stack' => 'overflow',
    ),
);

echo array_to_xml($test_array, new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>'))->asXML();
```

I want to change Tag name to Pascal case i used ucwords too its not working in the server

Comment: ucwords working in localhost

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `ucwords()` you are both doing it on a SimpleXMLElement, but also your not storing the value returned...

```
is_array($v)
    ? ucwords(array_to_xml($v, $xml->addChild($k)))
    : ucwords($xml->addChild($k, $v));
```

Instead you should just use it when using `addChild()`, applying it to the name of the element being created

```
is_array($v)
    ? array_to_xml($v, $xml->addChild(ucwords($k)))
    : $xml->addChild(ucwords($k), $v);
```

Which with your test data gives...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><BlaPo>1</BlaPo><Items>1</Items><Another_array><Stack>overflow</Stack></Another_array></root>
```

Comment: same result :( its not changing

Comment: I've added the result I get in the answer, which is what I'd expect.

Comment: yup in localhost i am getting the same answer but in server its showing as this

<response><packagetype>ITEM</packagetype><items>9</items><totalkgs>90</totalkgs><totalcubic>0</totalcubic><length>4</length><width>5</width><height>6</height></response>

Comment: These are totally different to what you had originally, but they still should work with the code above.

Comment: can you help me with this code

<?php
function arrayToXml($array, $rootElement = null, $xml = null) {
    $_xml = $xml;
   
    if ($_xml === null) {
      $_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($rootElement !== null ? $rootElement : '<root/>');
    }
   
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
      if (is_array($v)) { //nested array
         arrayToXml($v, $k, $_xml->addChild($k));
      } else {
        $_xml->addChild($k, $v);
      }
    }
   
    return $_xml->asXML();
  }
 echo arrayToXml(array('testOne'  => array('testOneInnerInner' => 'content')));

Comment: If you look at the answer - you need to use `ucwords($k)` in each call to `addChild()`.

Comment: its because of html 
through this function it solved htmlentities($xml_data)